# Скрипт должен уметь принимать с переменных окружения разрешение искомых файлов,не работает скрипт

Tags: javascript, node.js

Скрипт должен уметь принимать с переменных окружения разрешение искомых файлов.Уточню,что являюсь новичком в node,выдает ошибки ,пробовал чистить кеш -не помогло.
[image: .js]

Comment: Такая запись переменных окружения в винде не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Под windows запускайте так:
`set EXT=[".mp3", ".acc"] & node C:\Users\__yourpath__.js`

PS. Без кавычек в `EXT=[".mp3", ".acc"]`. Либо `EXT="['.mp3', '.acc']"`.